# The $n^{th}$ derivative of the function $f(x) = \frac{1}{(1 – x)^2}$ at the point $x = 0,$ where $n$ is even, is

Tags: calculus, derivatives

The $n^{th}$ derivative of the function $$f(x) = \frac{1}{(1 – x)^2}$$ at the point $x = 0,$ where $n$ is even, is

A) $n\times$ ${n}\choose{2}$

B) $n!$

C)$0$

Differentiating $f(x)$ twice does not help much. Differentiating $f(x)$ four times clearly points to the fact the the answer is $n!$

Is there a less clumsy way of arriving at the answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a hint : rewrite it as $$f(x) = \frac{1}{(1 – x)^2}
=(1-x)^{-2}$$so
you can take some derivarion and find (by induction) the formula

$$f(x)=(1-x)^{-2}\\f'=f^{(1)}=(-2)\times (1-x)^{-2-1} \ \times (-1)=(+2)(1-x)^{-3}\\
f''=f^{(2)}=(+2)(-3)\times (1-x)^{-3-1}\ \times (-1)=(3!)(1-x)^{-4}\\
f'''=f^{(3)}=(3!)(-4)\times (1-x)^{-4-1}\ \times (-1)=(4!)(1-x)^{-5}\\ \vdots$$

Answer (score 3):

Use the fact that\begin{align}f(x)&=\frac1{(1-x)^2}\\&=\left(\frac1{1-x}\right)'\\&=(1+x+x^2+x^3+\cdots)'\\&=1+2x+3x^2+4x^3+\cdots\end{align}

Answer (score 2):

Let $F(x):=\frac{1}{1-x}$. If $|x|<1$ it holds that $F(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n$.

Now, $f(x)=F'(x)$, so fo $|x|<1$
$$f(x)=\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n\right)'=\sum_{n=1}^\infty n x^{n-1}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty(n+1)x^n.
$$
Now recall that the Taylor series expansion at $x=0$ of $f(x)$ should be $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \dfrac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!} x^n$. So
$$\frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}=(n+1)\iff f^{(n)}(0)=(n+1)!$$